# Node.js fs workaround

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, fs

I'm using node and webpack to run a UI I've been designing on react. Some of the packages I use require fs - functions like `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/file.txt');` return a missing type error.

I've read that fs tries to access the file system which won't work on a browser due to privacy concerns. This is understandable.

What is the best explicit alternative ie. when I download a package (for example `npm install pdf-kit --s`) and it doesn't work due to using fs, what can I do to make it work?

Thanks

**Update:**

I've tried adding `"target": "node"` and

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty',
}
```

to webpack config, both to no avail. The specific error I am getting is

`TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`

Very keen for a specific workaround - not sure how to work with these packages that have fs...

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-285598881

Comment: In what environment are you running it where you need to read files? If it's on the web, send web requests.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I'm running a node localhost server using "npm start", on my ubuntu machine

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks felix - just tried and unfortunately no luck

Comment: if a package absolutely requires `fs`, then the alternative is to find an alternative package that doesn't require `fs`

Comment: If a package made for node requires fs, and won't work otherwise, what is the package used for?

Comment: @Dave it's meant to be used only in node.js not browser environment

Comment: @MilosMosovsky Apologies to get further away from the topic but the bottom of Pdfkit website describes browser usage and I can't get rid of the fs error for the life of me - is there an easy fix regarding browser usage? http://pdfkit.org/

Comment: check `Browser Usage` section, there is explicitly stated that you need to mock `fs` with browserify or polyfills

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has already been answered in the comments so I'll summarize it here:

'fs' or file system is part of node. If a package requires 'fs' it is probably meant to be used with node and not the client or browser environment.

The package in question happens to have browser support using blobs. http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html#using_pdfkit_in_the_browser

credit to Jaromanda X and Milos Mosovsky